# array based on a sentence in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sentence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

How do I read a bunch of words separated by spaces into an array?

Say I have this sentence:

"I like frogs"

And this array:

```
string mySentenceArray[2]
```

I would like to make

```
mySentenceArray[0] = I
mySentenceArray[1] = like
mySentenceArray[2] = frogs
```

Just as an example. (Please no one tell me to hard code the sentence I just wrote, it's an example.)

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: Just use boost, or write your own function. It is not even hard.

Comment: Don't use the solution in the link. It is poorly designed and no elegance as it says.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a string into a series of tokens and put those tokens into an array. Consider this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: `strtok` is awkward to use on a `std::string`, since it requires a mutable character array, and there's no way to access that directly from the `string`. It's also not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. Use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/). But it's C-function, not C++. Mixing C and C++ is bad style. Moreover `strtok` function isn't threadsafe.
2. Use any of [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) method. It's complicated.
3. Use [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) class. It needs too much steps.
4. Use [boost::algorithm::string::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3184031). I prefer this way. It's simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I had some other uses to justify adding an extra library, I'd probably just using a `stringstream`:

```
std::istringstream buffer("I like frogs");

std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer)), 
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just the standard library:

```
istringstream sentence("I like frogs");
vector<string> words(
    (istream_iterator<string>(sentence)), 
    (istream_iterator<string>()));
```

Note that unnecessary-seeming parentheses are actually necessary on at least one of the constructor arguments, otherwise you will be vexed by the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Alternatively, Boost provides some [useful string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/string_algo.html), including `split`:

```
string sentence("I like frogs");
vector<string> words;
boost::algorithm::split(words, sentence, boost::algorithm::is_space());
```